# React Hooks function component with controlled rendering based on state/prop values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

One of the benefits of being able to use `shouldComponentUpdate` on a React Class component is the ability to control the render based on a condition rather than just a change in state/prop values.

What is the preferred way to make this optimization using react hooks in a function component?

In the example below, the class component does not re-render if it is (or is staying) in a closed state, even if it has new children.

```
class DrawerComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any,
  }

  state = {
    isOpen: false,
  }

  // only re-render if the drawer is open or is about to be open.
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.isOpen || nextState.isOpen;
  }

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>           
        <div onClick={this.toggleDrawer}>
          Drawer Title
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.isOpen ? this.props.children : null}
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Function component counterpart (without optimization):

```
function DrawerComponent({ children }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function toggle() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  } 

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={toggle}>
        Drawer Title
      </div>
      <div>{isOpen ? children : null}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, in my opinion there's no need for a `shouldComponentUpdate` optimization. It will already be fast since you're not rendering the `children` when the drawer is closed. The cost of running the functional component will be fairly negligible.

That said, if you did want to implement the equivalent behavior in a functional component, you could use `React.memo` and supply a custom `areEqual` function: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo.

Comment: As far as I recall, given your example, calling `setIsOpen` with the same value twice won't cause a re-render. The value has to pass a strict equality `===` check.

Comment: I think you'd need `useCallback` for that. However, I'm not trying to catch a re-render from `setIsOpen`, rather, a change in children while `isOpen === false`

Comment: I've put this codesandbox together to demonstrate that passing in the same value to a setX doesn't cause a re-render, even with an array that has a new item:

https://codesandbox.io/s/0ypy38q9rw

Comment: @JamieKudla if you had a good reason to, you could memoize the element tree you're returning in your function and return the previous value if the drawer is closed. React then will not bother diffing or otherwise processing the output. Alternatively you could have a child component that gets both `children` and `isOpen` as props and prevents the render with `React.memo` as described. However, this is really all overkill in this scenario.

Comment: @Joru Not specific to this scenario, just curious how something like that could be handled. I think creating a new component that gets the state values in as props and handling via `memo` is the answer I'm looking for, thanks!.